# Use of bm package change symbols

Tags: bm

The following code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eulerpx,bm}

\begin{document}

$a<b\quad\bm{a<b}$

\end{document}
```

Provides the following output:

[image]

The inequality symbol is not changed when I use, say, `newpxmath` instead. The problem seems to be indeed with the `eulerpx` package. How can this be solved?

Comment: I’m pretty sure this is a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what all this breaks, but I redefined a symbol font and made `<` active inside of `\bm`.

The `\begingroup...\endgroup` isolates the catcode change, while still allowing binary operators inside the `\bm` to see what is outside of the `\bm`, shown in the MWE as `y\bm{-y}`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eulerpx,bm}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}    {U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\let\svbm\bm
\renewcommand\bm{\begingroup\catcode`<=\active \xbm}
\newcommand\xbm[1]{\svbm{#1}\endgroup}
\let\svlt<
{\catcode`<=\active \gdef<{\mathop{\mathrm{\svlt}}}}
\begin{document}
$a<b\quad\bm{a<b}\quad y\bm{-y}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

To apply this approach to both `<` and `>` relations requires just a little extra:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eulerpx,bm}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}    {U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\let\svbm\bm
\renewcommand\bm{\begingroup%
  \catcode`>=\active %
  \catcode`<=\active %
  \xbm}
\newcommand\xbm[1]{\svbm{#1}\endgroup}
\let\svlt<
\let\svgt>
{\catcode`>=\active 
\gdef>{\mathop{\mathrm{\svgt}}}
\catcode`<=\active 
\gdef<{\mathop{\mathrm{\svlt}}}}
\begin{document}
$a<b\quad\bm{a<>b}\quad y\bm{-y}$
\end{document}
```